# What kind of JST connector will fit this stepper motor?

Tags: connector, stepper-motor

I'm not familiar with JST connectors so please bear with me. According to the datasheet ([here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/61957.pdf?_ga=2.92913365.959044832.1559785822-521642061.1551237749&_gac=1.208979622.1556873392.EAIaIQobChMImIi8p_3-4QIVSA4rCh33sQ6TEAkYASABEgL7AvD_BwE)) this stepper uses a JST S11B-ZR female connector.

1) I'm confused since based on my understanding, S11B refers to the number of leads (11), but this stepper requires only 6. Is the male part also 11 leads but with just the 6 relevant leads connected?

2) Are there complete JST connector+cable assemblies for sale that I can just plug and play without needing to crimp my own?

3) Failing that, isit possible to simply hookup standard 2.54mm pitch jumper wires to the stepper JST connector?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the reference to the S11B-ZR in the datasheet you linked. It is possible that not all contacts in the 11 way commector are populated<sup>1</sup>. The datasheet should be clear which contacts are being used.

The S11B-ZR has a 1.5 mm pitch, so a 2.54 or 1.27 mm contra-connector won't fit. You might want to cut off the original connector and solder it to a connector of your own choice (keeping the voltage and current rating in mind).

1) For high voltages, it is possible that only pin 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 and 11 are populated in order to create creepage distance. But I wonder if that is the case in your stepper motor.

**EDIT**
If you want the best datasheet, you need to search the manufacturer's site.
I didn't find the MY7001 you linked to, but did find the [MY14HY7](http://www.astrosyn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/MY14HY7-1-Technical-Datasheet.pdf) which seems to me **very** similar.
If you look closely to the picture in the right upper corner, it reveals how the leads are populated in the housing: on positions 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 and 11.
BTW, the MY7001 states it has 4 No. of leads...

Comment: Its pretty well hidden but you can see the letters "JST S11B-ZR" on the bottom right diagram. The problem is, as you said, the documentation is whack and doesn't state which pin goes to which.

Comment: @Darrel, please be informed by the EDIT.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The mating connector to the [S11B-ZR](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/S11B-ZR-LF-SN/455-1678-ND/926585) is the [ZHR-11](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/ZHR-11/455-1191-ND/608632). They are likely not using all the pins available.

*Note that the ZHR-11 is just a housing and you would install the contacts so you would choose which pins to install/use.

[image]